# cursorAdapter loads after the next line of code is executed

Tags: android, sqlite, android-cursoradapter

I have this cursorAdapter for which I define a new object. Once, the object 'itemAdapter' is declared, I get the names of all the Strings which are loaded from the bindView method into an array(Names).

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int arg0, int arg1, Intent arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("success", "On activity result");
    super.onActivityResult(arg0, arg1, arg2);
    if(arg1==RESULT_OK){
        db=new DatabaseControl(this);
        db.open();
        CategoryCursorAdapter itemAdapter=new CategoryCursorAdapter(this, db.getItemCursor(-1), CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER, "item_name",1,db);
        iFrag.getListView().setAdapter(itemAdapter);

        Log.d("success", String.valueOf(itemAdapter.Names.size()));

    }
}
```

Problem is that the system executes the 'log.d'(last line) command before the decleration of 'itemAdapter'. Since the 'Names' array is only filled with values after itemAdapter has been declared the logcat shows the size of Names array as 0.

I have confirmed that the names array does not remain empty once itemAdapter has been declared.

please help!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You have several wrong issues in your code

1. DO NOT MAKE DB OPERATIONS in onActivityResult

onActivityResult is run before onResume - thus if the onActivityResult is slow, the user will see a black screen for a little while (do you want that?)

1. DB Operations should be asynchronous if possible, with a callback, on which you can set the contents of it inside the adapter
   perhaps in your case they  are asynchornous, as you did not tell us what "getItemCursor(-1)" does
2. if the db operation is asynchronous what happens is

you launch the async request, the code continues to run, and sometime when the result comes, it gets set to the adapter

the reason why this code may still work is because itemAdapter gets kept in the memory, as your listview has a reference to it, once it updates (and somewhere down the line you will use notifyDataSetChanged) , since the reference to the itemAdapter is still there, it will update your listview

if you take a look at the loader callbacks (the ones designed to load cursors asynchroniously), this is what they do

you create an adapter with a null cursor, and when the cursor finished loading, you swap your cursor

[reference to loader callbacks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks.html)